# Kali Linux can't start X with Nvidia driver

Tags: boot, kali-linux, nvidia

I have a MSI laptop with an Intel i7-7700HQ which has onboard graphics, and a GTX 1050. I am dual booting Kali Linux fresh install and Windows 10. I'm fairly new to Kali Linux. When the system starts it boots to the login screen, however when I enter my login it goes gray screen. I have no access to a terminal shortcuts. I have seen suggestions that this is an Nvidia driver problem.

[image: photo of the screen when I can get it to terminal]

Comment: If you are ***fairly new to kali***, you may want to try it out in a VM first... [Virtualbox runs in Windows](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)... but it's unlikely most Kali questions will be answered here because [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Comment: HOW did you Boot? Is it a Windows Boot or a Linux Boot?  Can you access by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1 ? It could be your graphics driver. Look here: https://journalxtra.com/linux/desktop-recovery/the-definitive-guide-to-getting-your-linux-desktop-back/ scroll down to "Solution Seven: switch to a basic graphics driver" A temporary fix, but you might be able to work from there.

Comment: I’m booting from the Linux grub. The ctrl + alt + F1 does not work at all. Also an interesting note, on normal boot I can get to the log in screen and use the keyboard and mouse, however in recovery mode it fails before any login

Comment: Can you boot Kali from a live USB?

Comment: Yes I can boot from a live usb

Comment: On grub screen press `e` to open grub parameters. Replace `quiet` with `nomodeset quiet splash`. To make this change permanent once you reach desktop, edit the same in **/etc/default/grub.conf** and run **sudo update-grub**.

Answer (score 2):

As was apparently [answered in a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/403934/kali-linux-cant-start-x-with-nvidia-driver#comment722399_403934):

On grub screen press `e` to open grub parameters. Replace `quiet` with `nomodeset quiet splash`. To make this change permanent once you reach desktop, edit the same in `/etc/default/grub.conf` and run `sudo update-grub`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem in dual booting.
Boot into Kali in the login screen press ctrl+alt+F2 or F4 i forget.
This will take you to a terminal log into your root account then run apt-get install lightdm .
It will ask you to choose between lightdm or gdm3, choose lightdm and reboot.
Should work after that.